# How to iterate over rows using apply to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to iterate over rows using the apply method. The first row "1" is a string with sentence, the rest of the rows are floats. I will take this rows to use it into a function. Something like this:

```py
def my_function(row1, row2, row3, row4):
  if row["1"]:
    '''do some stuff here with the rows'''
  return # the dataframe with the modification to the float rows "2" "3" "4" 

df['row1'] = df['row1'].apply(lambda row: my_function(row['row1'], row['row2'], row['row3'], row['row4']))

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

An example: the first row is a sentence and if has any "a" in the sentence, then we proceed to modify the float rows, and the function will return the modification of this three last rows.

Comment: The question does not seem to have any details on what went wrong? Also, you probably do not want to refer to `row["a"]` in `my_function()`, but rather to `row1`.

Comment: @VirtualScooter 
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`. Changing the code as requested

Comment: Anecdotally, if you can avoid some sort of `.apply` and iteration logic, absolutely do it; you may find you see ridiculous (100x) speedups using a vectorized approach!

Comment: @ti7 you mean something like a for loop with iterrows() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the axis, for default `apply` applies a function along columns. On the other hand, you should decide if your function is going to use a row as argument or single elements, to be honest I prefer the first one. Your code could be something like this:
You need this one:

```py
def my_function(row):
  if row["a"] ... :
    # do something
  if row["b"] ... :
    # do something
  return something

df_negative['new_a'] = df_negative['a'].apply(my_function, axis=1)  # without lambda function
```

Comment: Exactly as you wrote it: `TypeError: my_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: what worked was something like this: `df_negative['a'] = df_negative.apply(lambda row: my_function(row['a'], row['i']), axis=1)`